# Completely delete SKSpriteNode variable

Tags: swift, skspritenode

I have a subclass of SKSpriteNode called 'backgroundMusic' that consists of a SKSpriteNode and a AVAudioPlayer file. The objective is to completely delete 'backgroundMusic' after i instantiate it. I try to do :

```
backgroundMusic.removeFromParent()
```

but it only removes the SKSpriteNode and not the AVAudioPlayer.

The main issue is that inside of this subclass, I call a bunch of functions within other functions, and when i try to empty the subclass by:

```
backgroundMusic = nil
```

the process of calling all the functions still is occurring and causes issues when i re-instantiate it. What i believe will work is if I delete 'backgroundMusic' completely, which will stop the function calling process, and then later re-instantiate it when i need to, it should work fine with no issues. How can I do this?

**EDIT** I tried:

```
self.delete(backgroundMusic)
```

and it crashed the application. Should I use this? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

This happened because you havent configure [Audio Session](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875)

Some code for playing:

```
import AVFoundation

var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func playAudio() {
    // Set the sound file name & extension
    let alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Flip 02", ofType: "wav")!)

    // Preperation
    try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers)
    try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

    // Play the sound
    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    } catch {
        print("there is \(error)")
    }
}
```

Details from the docs:

> AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
>
> Mixes audio from this session with audio from other active sessions.
>
> Valid only if the session category is
>   AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord or AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback.
>   (Implicit if the session category is AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient.)
>
> If you activate your session while using this option, your app’s audio
>   will not interrupt audio from other apps (such as the Music app). If
>   not using this option (or a category that is implicitly mixable),
>   activating your session will interrupt other nonmixable sessions.

To stop you can do:

```
do {

        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)

    } catch let error as NSError {

        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
```

Comment: This isn't my issue. I want to know how to delete my variable 'backgroundMusic' after instantiating it. The music is fine.

Comment: You must provide more backgroundMusic code, your question dont explain if your music will continue after stop it.